# WordPress add_theme_support('post-thumbnails') is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm new to WordPress development and I saw a video on how to add featured images. For some reason it's not working and I can't really figure out why. The option for Featured Image is not showing at all, so I don't really know how to fix it.

I've tried googling to see if people have experienced the same thing and from what I've seen it's usually syntax errors, however I don't think I have that.

I've tried deleting and adding it on again, but to no avail. I've also tried adding an array as a second argument to `add_theme_support()` but still nothing. I've also tried having the `add_action()` function before the custom function, and that hasn't worked either.

Here is the code in the functions.php file:

```php
function Image_theme_setup(){
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'Image_theme_setup');
```

Comment: First try to switch to a default theme and check , you will know if the issue is with the theme.

Comment: @Faisal I changed the theme and the featured image showed up, so it has to be something with my theme, but i just can't figure out what

Comment: are u coding the theme from scratch ?